# Destroy AWS resources of a failed/canceled Terraform apply

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

So I've used a lot AWS CDK and if a deployment fails I can destroy de Cloudformation stack an any service created is destroyed. But using Terraform I end up having the same problem of cancelling or failing a deployment (terraform apply) but some resources has been deployed before it failed, however if I run terraform destroy it does not know that these resources has been deployed... so is the only way to clean up these resources manually? Or I'm missing something?

(I know that this deployment should be run in a CICD, but if the pipeline fails the deployment the problem will be the same: some orphan AWS resources that have to be deleted manually).

Comment: What if you do `terraform refresh` before you do `terraform destroy`?

Comment: what do you mean "some resources has been deployed before it failed"? Terraform manages resources created by Terraform and in the tfstate, you cannot destroy resources not listed in tfstate

Comment: So the problem is basically this: https://community.gruntwork.io/t/cleanup-of-terraform-apply-partial-fails/420/2 
So I do a terraform apply, I cancel it but it has created some subnets, but terraform.tfstate is empty, so no terraform destroy or terraform refresh can delete these subnets created for instance. @FranxiHidro

Comment: @Jens the terraform refresh seems like a good idea but I think that if the 'apply' command is canceled it does not save the state. I might be wrong but it happened me some times that the terraform.tfstate does not save the state of the resources created if cancelled.

Comment: As I remember, It still saves the completed resources in the tfstate.

Comment: I'm thinking of importing created resources to state files by using `terraform import` then you can run `terraform destroy`.

Comment: @vidura at that point you can just destroy the resource yourself.

Comment: Terraform still saves its state file even if some resources error out. The only time when this does not happen is if terraform itself crashes directly or if e.g. the credentials used to interact with some remote state expire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick test and even terraform apply failed in the middle, it still keeps completed resources in terraform.tfstate

File main.tf

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "ap-southeast-1"
}

resource "aws_vpc" "test" {
  cidr_block       = "10.0.0.0/16"
  instance_tenancy = "default"

  tags = {
    Name = "test"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "sub1" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.test.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.1.0/24"

  tags = {
    Name = "sub1"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "sub2" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.test.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.2.0/24"

  tags = {
    Name = "sub2"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "sub3" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.test.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/8"

  tags = {
    Name = "sub3"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table" "rtb1" {
  depends_on = [aws_subnet.sub3]
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.test.id

  route = []

  tags = {
    Name = "rtb1"
  }
}
```

Terraform plan passed and failed on terraform apply as below:
[image]

You can see the state list and this is the result of terraform destroy
[image]

Comment: Yes you're right, I replicated your example and also tried again to replicate with the code I had problems and tfstate is indeed created even cancelled. I suppose I had some kind of a bug these times where my tfstate was empty. I'm running version 1.0.0 of terraform, I'll update to 1.0.1. Anyways, thanks for your help and nice to see this was only a bug and terraform can handle this correctly! Also I suppose that a good way to avoid any state problems will be to use terraform cloud.